# Troubles reconnecting to MySQL database from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I can successfully log on to the database with this:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

connString.Server = textEditServer.Text;
connString.UserID = "root";
connString.Password = textEditServerPassword.Text;
connString.Database = "geysercontrol";
conn.ConnectionString = connString.ConnectionString;

try
{
     conn.Open();
     Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["ConnectionString"].DefaultValue = conn.ConnectionString;
     conn.Close();
}
catch (MySqlException)
{
      XtraMessageBox.Show("No connection could be established");
}
```

But when I try to use the ConnectionString property to reconnect with different class, I get an MySQLException saying

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What can be the possible causes to this? The page on possible causes on the MySQL website doesn't include my situation.

The code I use to reconnect is:

```
 connection = new MySqlConnection();
 connection.ConnectionString = (String)Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["ConnectionString"].DefaultValue;
 connection.Open();
```

And the connectionString definitely is the same in both cases. It is:

```
server=localhost;User Id=root;database=geysercontrol;password=password
```

Comment: Not sure, may be connection string is wrong. Try to use 'host=localhost;...' instead of 'server=localhost;...'.

Comment: @Devart It seems (according to the VS debugger) when do the assignment: connection.ConnectioString = (String)... that it changes 'host' to 'server' anyways. Also, 'server=localhost;...' is what the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder gave me anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add persist security info = true to the connection string I think.

If it were me though I wouldn't put connection string with a password in it in there. If you ever call Save, it will be exposed in the config file.